# Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth_web'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mobile-application, android-studio-4.0

So I was just trying to implement google sign in feature in my app when I encountered this error

Here is the entire text:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 362

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth_web'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Things I have done:-

1.I have already added required plug ins in dependencies

```
dependencies:
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
```

2.My flutter is up to date .

My android/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app/build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.memesgram23"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Stackoverflow is telling me that the post has mostly code so I am adding this line so that is balances out.I don't know what details I could add I think stackoverflow should so something about this algorithm .

Comment: add ur build.gradle file

Comment: @PeterHaddad Where should I add it .( I am new to Stackoverflow).

Comment: to the question, just copy it from android studio and edit your question and paste it

Comment: add also the app/build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade the `minSdkVersion` to the following:

```
 minSdkVersion 23
```

Also add `firebase_core` to `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.0
```

Comment: How to upgrade the mini sdk version?

Comment: in app/build.gradle just change it there

Comment: same error! I just changed the text from 16 to 23 anything else?

Comment: did u add firebase_core and save it? Close the ide, open it again and rerun